# i get undefined result when i want to get the value from input box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value from the input in the html code and edit it, then put it in the div, but I get undefined.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id='doller'>
<button onclick="convertUsdToRiyal()">convert usd to Riyal</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="js1.js"></script>
```

JS

```
function convertUsdToRiyal() {
    'use strict';
    var amount = document.getElementById('doller').Value,
        result = 3.75 * amount,
        massage = document.getElementById('result');
    massage.innerHTML = amount;**//here i get undefined**
}
```

Comment: typo: `Value` should be `value` (lowercase `v`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "value" attribute should be in lower case, because javascript is a case sensitive language. So the instruction will be :

```
var amount = document.getElementById("doller").value.
```

Here is the code in es6 (ECMAscript 2015) for the convertUsdToRiyal() function:

```
convertUsdToRiyal = () => {
  let amount = document.getElementById("doller").value;
  result = 3.75 * amount;
  massage = document.getElementById("result");
  massage.innerHTML = result;
};
```

or just simply:

```
 convertUsdToRiyal = () => {

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 3.75*document.getElementById("doller").value;
};
```

Comment: thanks...is it necessary to learn es6 !!!   i  did not finish javascript yet.

Comment: It is not a big thing and it does not take big time to learn it. It is just kind of modern js. It makes your code more clean and easy to inderstand. Here is some new features of es6:

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('doller').Value` should be changed to `document.getElementById('doller').value`.
`Value` should be lowercase.

```js
/*global console*/
function convertUsdToRiyal() {
    var amount = document.getElementById('doller').value,
        result = 3.75 * amount,
        massage = document.getElementById('result');
    console.log(amount);
    massage.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='doller'>
<button  onclick="convertUsdToRiyal()">convert usd to Riyal</button>
<div id ="result"></div>
```